# Could not handle exceptions inside a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

Language : C#

I use a backgroundworker to run my long job. I happen to see an exception, which I should ignore. When I handle the exception in the code block, it is not caught in the block itself. Instead it is caught , where I invoked backgroundworker's dowork.

**Problem Situation**

```
    Backgroundworker1_dowork()
    {
      try
       {
         fun1();
       }
      catch(Exception e)
       {
      console.writeline("bg block");
        }
    }
   void fun1()
   {
     try
        { 
            throw new exception("ex1");
        }
     catch(Exception ex)
       { 
           Console.writeline("code block");
       }
    }

   output: bg block Expected: code block
```

Can any one help me...

Comment: Not without being able to see what code is producing this behavior...

Comment: I think it throws the exception in Backgroundworker1_dowork() before executing fun1() or skips fun1(). See the call stack of your exception

Comment: After adjusting the code above to build (dowork parms, etc), I'm consistently getting the expected result.  Could you post a buildable failing example?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you provide will not compile, so it is hard to determine the problem. Yet, the call to fun1 is failing or the catch block in fun1 is failing.

I would put a `Debug.WriteLine("In fun1");` before the try of fun1. If you do not see this in the output then you know the call to fun1 is failing. If you see this output, then you know the catch block is failing.